# Search in ORMLite by part of text

Tags: android, sql, search, ormlite

I need to search by part of word with ORMLite(j256) on Android. For example, when my query is "war" I want get results with "**war**y" "**war**rant" "**war**d" etc. fields values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, every ORM allows executing raw SQL statements and ORMLite(j256) does that as well by providing `queryRaw()` method.

Now using the capability of this method of executing raw SQL, you can build a query something like:

```
Select * from tableName where something LIKE 'war%'
```

Refer more about building queries in their documentation http://ormlite.com/docs/ormlite.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much